# What are the advantages of FastBitmapDrawable compared to Bitmap?

Tags: android, drawable

```
package com.android.launcher;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;

class FastBitmapDrawable extends Drawable {
    private Bitmap mBitmap;

    FastBitmapDrawable(Bitmap b) {
    mBitmap = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
    return mBitmap.getWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
    return mBitmap.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public int getMinimumWidth() {
    return mBitmap.getWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public int getMinimumHeight() {
    return mBitmap.getHeight();
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return mBitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the right question must be: What are the advantages of FastBitmapDrawable compared to BitmapDrawable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really fair to compare a FastBitmapDrawable to a Bitmap.  Traditional Bitmaps are just a type of `Object` in Java.  FastBitmapDrawables however, are a custom class written to extend the functionality of the `Drawable` class, not the `Bitmap` class.

A FastBitmapDrawable **contains** a traditional Bitmap, and makes a few assumptions that make it convenient to use in certain situations. This is the crucial line:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);
```

This FastBitmapDrawable assumes that the bitmap will be placed at (0, 0) on the screen, and that no special Paint object will be used to draw it.

Really it's just a convenience.  You could get the same performance by manually setting the position to (0, 0) and the Paint to null in a normal `Drawable`, but this class does that for you automatically.

Comment: Earlier I compared from this point of view

`imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`
`imageView.setImageDrawable(fastBitmapDrawable);`

With your explaination of the crucial line, it really helps me to understand the use of `FastBitmapDrawable`

Answer (score 0):

This is a utility class, in case you want to alter how a `Bitmap` is drawn. As it is, it doesn't add any functionality other than default behavior.

Comment: Why is it called FastBitmapDrawable?

Comment: It's quick(simple) code, it doesn't draw faster. It's not a good name I think.

Comment: Maybe because they choose to call it like that? It helps to draw a bitmap without the need to define an own drawable, that's the reason why it's fast, so...